# Javascript - Dependency injection and promises

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pass an object around in JS (with some jQuery thrown in). :)

I want to call the `FlappyBarHelper.getUserPropertyCount()` method once the `promise.success` function has run. I've tried passing `this.FlappyBarHelper` to :

```
return $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: 'get-the-score',
              flappy: this.FlappyBarHelper,
          });
```

But that still makes `flappy` undefined in `promise.success`

My full code is:

```
function Rating(FlappyBarHelper) {
    this.FlappyBarHelper = FlappyBarHelper; 
}

Rating.prototype.attachRaty = function(property_id)
{   

    var promise = this.getPropertyScoreAjax(property_id);

    promise.success(function (data) {


        $('#'+property_id).raty({
           click: function (score, evt) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '/set-the-score',
                })
                    .done(function (msg) {
                        $('#extruderTop').openMbExtruder(true);  
                            //**** FlappyBarHelper is undefined at this point ****///
                        FlappyBarHelper.getUserPropertyCount('.flap');
                    });  


            }
        });


    });

};

Rating.prototype.getPropertyScoreAjax = function(property_id)
{

      return $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: 'get-the-score',
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read from the documentation of ($.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> The this reference within all callbacks is the object in the context option passed to $.ajax in the settings; if context is not specified, this is a reference to the Ajax settings themselves.

Therefore you should pass your variable along the multiple call you are doing:

```
Rating.prototype.attachRaty = function(property_id){   

  var promise = this.getPropertyScoreAjax(property_id);
  // it's best to use done
  promise.done(function (data) {

    $('#'+property_id).raty({
      // use proxy to keep context when the click will be received
      click: $.proxy(function(score, evt) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: '/set-the-score',
          // propagate your variable
          FlappyBarHelper: this.FlappyBarHelper
        }).done(function (msg) {
          $('#extruderTop').openMbExtruder(true);  
          // here it should be defined
          this.FlappyBarHelper.getUserPropertyCount('.flap');
        });  
      }, this);
    });
  });
};

Rating.prototype.getPropertyScoreAjax = function(property_id) {
  return $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'get-the-score',
    // propagate your variable
    FlappyBarHelper: this.FlappyBarHelper
  });
}
```

You can also consider making a closure variable:

```
Rating.prototype.attachRaty = function(property_id){   
  // here is the closure variable
  var helper = this.FlappyBarHelper;

  var promise = this.getPropertyScoreAjax(property_id);
  // it's best to use done
  promise.done(function (data) {

    $('#'+property_id).raty({
      click: function(score, evt) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: '/set-the-score'
        }).done(function (msg) {
          $('#extruderTop').openMbExtruder(true);  
          // you can still use the defined variable: power (and danger) of closures
          helper.getUserPropertyCount('.flap');
        });  
      }, this);
    });
  });
};

Rating.prototype.getPropertyScoreAjax = function(property_id) {
  return $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'get-the-score'
  });
}
```

Comment: pretty textbook answer. Thanks for the detailed explanation. I also read up on the difference 'success vs done'. :)